# How can I reset/get back razor intellisense and syntax highlighting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I had a problem with my Visual Studio 2010 install - managed to sort it by a repair, and reinstall my addon's etc., but now the intellisense and syntax highlighting has disappeared from my cshtml files - I've reinstalled the asp.net mvc 3 RTM and that hasn't fixed it...I've trying a devenv /ResetSettings, but no change.

Is there anything else I can do to try and bring back my lovely highlighting?!

Comment: What kind of problem did you have that required you to repair VS? Do you by any chance have the C# 5.0 Async preview installed?

Comment: No I didnt have that installed. I had a problem with templates, duplicate ones, I removed some of them and then that seemed to muck up the installation, so I reinstall VS and got all the templates back successfully - feels like its some form of a registry problem... :-(

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio 2010 SP1 installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok solved it - When uninstalling MVC 3 Visual Studio Tools, I didnt uninstall asp.net webpages visual studio tools, which MVC 3 depends on, once I uninstalled this also and then reinstalled the MVC 3 RTM, my syntax highlights etc came back! phew!

Comment: Legend! Thanks heaps for that. I wouldn't have found that in a million years. Worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading "ASP.NET Web Pages with Razor Syntax" 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=B7937C34-3B53-47B7-AE17-5A72FA700472

Comment: Says I've got a later version installed :-(

Answer (score 0):

Just did this and it worked:

Uninstall:

- ASP.NET MVC 3 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools Update
- ASP.NET MVC 3 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools Update - ESN (Language pack, in my case)
- ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools Update
- ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools Update - ESN
- ASP.NET Web Pages - Visual Sutdio 2010 Tools Update
- ASP.NET Web Pages - Visual Sutdio 2010 Tools Update - ESN

Reinstall everything again. It worked without rebooting.